# Check if an array of Directories exist and add the value to a corresponding array of keys in a configuration file

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, configuration, key

```
        string[] userDirectoryInput = {userSourceDirectory, userDefaultDestination, userArchiveDestination, userDocumentDestination, userImageDestination, userMusicDestination, userVideoDestination};
        string[] directorySettings = { "SourceFolder", "DefaultFolder", "ArchiveFolder", "DocumentFolder", "ImageFolder", "MusicFolder", "VideoFolder" };

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);

        foreach(string input in userDirectoryInput) 
        {
            if(Directory.Exists(input)) 
                {
                   //soemthing like this
                   config.AppSettings.Settings[directorySettings].Value = input;


                }
                else 
                    {
                    MessageBox.Show(input + " is not a valid directory.", "Directory Error");
                    } 
        }
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

userDirectoryInput is an array of directories.
directorySettings is an array of key names.

I want to check if the directories are valid and enter the value in the corrisponding key (first in userDirectoryInput in first directorySettings, 5th with 5th, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Why not create class?  Too often programmers don't simply create a class to solve issues like this and complicate things with multiple obscure lists.

```
public class Entry
{
   public string Directory { get; set; }
   public string SettingName {get; set;}
   public bool Exists {get; private set;}

   public bool CheckDirectory(Configuration config){
        if (Directory.Exists(Directory ) ){
          config.AppSettings.Settings[directorySettings].Value = Directory;
          Exists = true;
          return true;
        }
        else{
          Exists = false;
          return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Then traverse a list of these entries..

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);

foreach(Entry entry in listOfEntries) 
{
   if ( entry.CheckDirectory(config) == false ){
     //handle error
   }
}
```